# Default environment as a skeleton for other environments

Tags: environments

I have a number of environments that have very similar definitions, one example of which is below.

```
\newcounter{definition}
\newenvironment{definition}[1][]{%
 \refstepcounter{definition}
 \global\mdfdefinestyle{definition}{linecolor=grey60, linewidth=3pt, skipabove=2\parskip,   skipbelow=0.4\parskip, topline=false, rightline=false, bottomline=false}
  \ifstrempty{#1}%
  {\begin{mdframed}[style=definition]
  {\bfseries{Definition~\thedefinition}\newline}
  \relax}
  {\begin{mdframed}[style=definition]
  {\bfseries{Definition~\thedefinition}} \,(#1)\newline\relax
}}{\end{mdframed}}
\renewcommand\thedefinition{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{definition}}
```

The other environments are very similar to this but with `theorem` in place of each `definition`, for example. How might one define a 'skeleton' environment that takes the environment name and correctly defines a new environment to correspond with that (including changing `\thedefinition` to `\thetheorem` and `Definition~` to `Theorem~`), but without relying on many other packages (I'm trying to learn how to write all my macros myself so that I don't have to rely too heavily on packages)?

In addition to this, is it a trivial extension to set it up so that I may define `\linewidth` and each of the box lines as arguments to this skeleton environment, so that the theorem environment has a larger left line and includes a right line too?

Of course, with only a handful of environments I could just define each of them separately as I have done already, but I would be very interested in seeing how this code would look in case there are a great deal of environments that can be altered globally at once. I am sure that this is a feature in the `amsthm` package for their default theorem style, but I don't know where to go to check the code that they implement (if someone could point me in the correct direction for that also, I would be very grateful!).

Comment: `\global\mdfdefinestyle` can't possibly be doing anything good, shouldn't that style definition just be done once, in the preamble not every time (and definitely never prefixed with `\global`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've included it since the definition changes with each environment type (thicker lines for different environments and such), and the `\global` prefix is admittedly just something I had copied from someone else --- I had considered removing it since I was unsure how relevant it is, but it hasn't yielded any errors (yet) so I kept it in. If you don't think it needs to be there, I'll get rid of it though!

Comment: but the style is specific to definition environment `\mdfdefinestyle{definition}`...  so why are you including it in every use of that environment. It should be like the definition you have of `\thedefininition` just done once.

Comment: `\global` never makes an error applies to the first non expandable token in the expansion of `\mdfdefinestyle` and then does nothing if that isn't a primitive assignment and makes that assignment global if it is.  So whatever it does it does by accident:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that all aspects of the original definition are correct (`\global` can not prefix `mdfdefinestyle` for example) but to parameterise it just use `#1` for definition and `\csname thedefinition\endcsname` for `\thedefinition`, and `##1` for `#1`.

```
\newcommand\mythmdef[1]{%
\newcounter{#1}%
\newenvironment{#1}[1][]{%
 \refstepcounter{#1}%
 \global\mdfdefinestyle{#1}{linecolor=grey60, linewidth=3pt, skipabove=2\parskip,   skipbelow=0.4\parskip, topline=false, rightline=false, bottomline=false}%
  \ifstrempty{##1}%
  {\begin{mdframed}[style=#1]%
  {\bfseries{\MakeUppercase#1~\csname the#1\endcsname}\newline}%
  \relax}%
  {\begin{mdframed}[style=#1]%
  {\bfseries{\MakeUppercase#1~\csname the#1\endcsname}} \,(##1)\newline\relax
}}{\end{mdframed}}%
\expandafter\renewcommand\csname the#1\endcsname{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{#1}}}
```

then you can go

```
\mythmdef{definition}
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer missed one, will fix:-)

Comment: This is perfect for the parameterisation I was after, thank you! As a side question, is it appropriate to comment off every line in a macro? I thought it was only for lines that would induce incorrect spacing and whatnot (unless that is all of the lines, I'm still learning).

Comment: @BillWallis I think all the `%` I added protect you from white space in the output, it's possible that some are not strictly needed but no point in analysing too deeply if in doubt add. it _always_ saves memory.